# AngularJs: can't get ng-model in ng-repeat in component's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `ng-model="model.ind[$index]"` to record which tag is active, then when I click the tag(the a tag) parentIndex and $index will be passed to my controller, and the `model.ind[$index]` would be set equal to current index.

However, in my function select, I can't get `this.model.tag[parentIndex]` and get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at angular.module.component.controller.select`

What can I do to fix this problem?

my component is:

```
<div class="filters-wrapper">
    <div class="filters-section" ng-repeat="tag in $ctrl.tagList track by $index">
        <p ng-model="model.ind[$index]" ng-init="model.ind[$index] = 0; parentIndex = $index" >{{tag.name}}</p>
        <a ng-repeat="t in tag.tags track by $index" class="filter"
           ng-class="{active:$index == model.ind[parentIndex]}"
           ng-click="$ctrl.select(parentIndex,$index)"
        >
            {{t}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my component js is :

```
angular.module('myApp').component('filterBar',{
    templateUrl: 'component/filter-bar/filter-bar.html',
    controller: ['$log',function filterBarCtrl($log){
        this.select = function(parentIndex,index){
            this.model.ind[parentIndex] = index;
        };
        this.selected = 0;

        this.model = {};

        this.tagList = [
            {
                name: 'type',
                tags:["a","b"]
            }
        ];
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$ctrl.model` in template for bind it with controller field. And `this.model.ind` must to be defined, if you want to use `$ctrl.model.ind[...]` in template